# Problem with rendering to Android on Sony Vegas 13 Pro

Tags: editing

Folks, I have a problem with rendering in Sony Vegas 13 Pro for the android.

I'm taking the vertically videos via my phone without changing any video and audio options.
On PC BEFORE and after rendering it looks like this: https://i.ibb.co/6DnfbJ3/Clipboard01.jpg

After I upload it to any of my android phones it looks like this: https://i.ibb.co/QbLdmRw/Clipboard02.jpg

I tried to change the codec, frame and bit rate and frame size but nothing helped.
My Android keep showing me this small videos regarding of parameters i chose.

Please advise what's wrong as on PC everything looks good.